# I need to convert this curl code into windows cmd

Tags: windows, http, curl, post, request

I have an email post code generated from `sendgrid` for an HTTP post but the code my default does not work in windows. Can anyone help me in executing it

```
export SENDGRID_API_KEY='******'

curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer $SENDGRID_API_KEY" \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "test@example.com"}]}],"from": {"email": "test@example.com"},"subject": "Sending with SendGrid is Fun","content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "and easy to do anywhere, even with cURL"}]}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6) PowerShell command.

Following are available switches for this command:

```
Invoke-WebRequest
      [-UseBasicParsing]
      [-Uri] <Uri>
      [-WebSession <WebRequestSession>]
      [-SessionVariable <String>]
      [-AllowUnencryptedAuthentication]
      [-Authentication <WebAuthenticationType>]
      [-Credential <PSCredential>]
      [-UseDefaultCredentials]
      [-CertificateThumbprint <String>]
      [-Certificate <X509Certificate>]
      [-SkipCertificateCheck]
      [-SslProtocol <WebSslProtocol>]
      [-Token <SecureString>]
      [-UserAgent <String>]
      [-DisableKeepAlive]
      [-TimeoutSec <Int32>]
      [-Headers <IDictionary>]
      [-MaximumRedirection <Int32>]
      [-MaximumRetryCount <Int32>]
      [-RetryIntervalSec <Int32>]
      [-Method <WebRequestMethod>]
      [-Proxy <Uri>]
      [-ProxyCredential <PSCredential>]
      [-ProxyUseDefaultCredentials]
      [-Body <Object>]
      [-Form <IDictionary>]
      [-ContentType <String>]
      [-TransferEncoding <String>]
      [-InFile <String>]
      [-OutFile <String>]
      [-PassThru]
      [-Resume]
      [-PreserveAuthorizationOnRedirect]
      [-SkipHeaderValidation] 
      [<CommonParameters>]
```

Following is an example to access we content using [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6) command:

```
$webResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138501/i-need-to-convert-this-curl-code-into-windows-cmd";
Write-Host "$webResponse";
```

You can [find complete documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6).